# LINQ to append to a StringBuilder from a String[]

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, stringbuilder

I've got a String array that I'm wanting to add to a string builder by way of LINQ.

What I'm basically trying to say is "For each item in this array, append a line to this StringBuilder".

I can do this quite easily using a foreach loop however the following code doesn't seem to do anything. What am I missing?

```
stringArray.Select(x => stringBuilder.AppendLine(x));
```

Where as this works:

```
foreach(String item in stringArray)
{
  stringBuilder.AppendLine(item);
}
```

Comment: i wouldn´t use the .Select command... isn´t the ForEach command available?

Comment: I've renamed StringBuilder and StringArray to use a lower case first char. Just to make it clear that I'm refering to instance variables and not types.

Comment: yes it is... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you insist on doing it in a LINQy way:

```
StringBuilder builder = StringArray.Aggregate(
                            new StringBuilder(),
                            (sb, s) => sb.AppendLine(s)
                        );
```

Alternatively, as [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/luke) pointed out in a comment on another post, you could say

```
Array.ForEach(StringArray, s => stringBuilder.AppendLine(s));
```

The reason that `Select` does not work is because `Select` is for projecting and creating an `IEnumerable` of the projection. So the line of code

```
StringArray.Select(s => stringBuilder.AppendLine(s))
```

does not iterate over the `StringArray` calling `stringBuilder.AppendLine(s)` on each iteration. Rather, it creates an `IEnumerable<StringBuilder>` that can be enumerated over.

I suppose that you could say

```
var e = stringArray.Select(x => stringBuilder.AppendLine(x));
StringBuilder sb = e.Last();
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

but that is really hideous.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Your answer explains why the Select method didn't achieve the result I wanted and why the foreach was working. I'll stick with the foreach. I was really just curious about what I was missing. Now I know.

Comment: Is Last() guaranteed to iterate?  Rather than just fetch stringArray[stringArray.count-1]?  I think I would have preferred ToList();

Answer (score 8):

Use the "ForEach" extension method instead of "Select".

```
stringArray.ToList().ForEach(x => stringBuilder.AppendLine(x));
```

or

```
Array.ForEach(stringArray, x => stringBuilder.AppendLine(x));
```

Comment: @GertArnold updated, based on your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET core then this will work:

```
stringBuilder.AppendJoin(Environment.NewLine, stringArray);
```

Although it's not leveraging LINQ, but it does get it done in one line without adding any extra code.

Comment: You should include a clarification that this method is available only in .NET Core, at least for now. It should also be in .NET 5 when that's officially released.

Comment: This is one of the things I love about the internet. 11 years on and we have a new answer! Amazing.

Answer (score -1):

```
stringArray.DoForAll(x => StringBuilder.AppendLine(x));
```

Where, `DoForAll` is an extension method:

```
public static class CommonExtensions 
{ 
    public static void DoForAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action) where T: class 
    { 
        if (action == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action"); 
        foreach (var item in items) 
            action(item);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've had this extension method for so long, I forgot is not part of the framework.
 public static class CommonExtensions
 {
  public static void DoForAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
   where T: class

  {
   if (action == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

   foreach (var item in items)
    action(item);  
  }
}

Comment: @vladhorby: One view on why `DoForAll` and other equivalent extensions are not implemented: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx