# Is it possible to construct a stringbuilder using a lambda function instead of foreach?

Tags: linq, functional-programming, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ to append to a StringBuilder from a String[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708247/linq-to-append-to-a-stringbuilder-from-a-string)

Forgive my functional programming noobiness, but is it even possible to use a lamba function to append each string in an array to a StringBuilder object?

Is it possible to turn this code:

```
// string[] errors = ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<ul>");

foreach (var error in errors)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", error);
}

sb.AppendLine("</ul");
return sb.ToString();
```

Into something like this:

```
// string[] errors = ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<ul>");

//I know this isn't right, I don't care about a return value
errors.All(s => sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", s));

sb.AppendLine("</ul");
return sb.ToString();
```

Thanks for any edification!

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708247/linq-to-append-to-a-stringbuilder-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but something like the following should work...

```
return errors.Aggregate(new StringBuilder("<ul>"), (sb,s) => sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", s))
             .Append("</ul>");
             .ToString();
```

Aggregate is an IEnumerable extension method... But I might have the order of agruments wrong. Personally, I do not think this buys you much since it less readable, and is doing a `foreach` internally anyway.

Comment: I think this should work, except the lambda function parameters should be "(sb, s) => .." (the first parameter is current state, which is the string builder, the second one is a signle error string from the 'errors' collection.

Comment: @Tomas: Thanks! That's what I intended. I've corrected the example. RWFP is excellent... Bravo!

Comment: I agree it's less readable, was more curious than anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Regarding readability - I think this is a case where partial function application could make the code a bit nicer. Imagine you could write just: Aggregate(..., StringBuilder.AppendFormat("<li>{0}<li>")). (Though this probably isn't something that could ever work nicely in C#)