# Append 'List' items to StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, list, iterator, stringbuilder

I tried to append the items in a `List<string>` to a `StringBuilder` with LINQ:

```
items.Select(i => sb.Append(i + ","));
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708247/linq-to-append-to-a-stringbuilder-from-a-string) which explains why the above doesn't work, but I couldn't find an `Each` of `ForEach` or anything similar on `List` which I could use instead.

Is there a neat way of doing this in a one-liner?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? ForEach is a method on the generic list in .Net 4.

Comment: yes I'm .Net 3.5 unfortunately

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a simple `foreach` loop. That way you have statements which modify the StringBuilder, instead of using an expression with side-effects.

And perhaps your problem is better solved with `String.Join(",", items)`.

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about `String.Join`. Sometimes I really need to break out of my Linq wankathon and remember how people programmed before :)

Answer (score 17):

```
items.ForEach(item => sb.Append(item + ","));
```

Comment: Note that you have to hang on to a List<T> not an IList<T> where this extension is no longer available. That's why I prefer to write my own ForEach that works on IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String [] items={"Jan","Feb","Mar"};
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
 foreach(var entity in items)
 {
   sb.Append(entity + Environment.NewLine);
 }
 Textbox1.Text=sb.tostring();
```

Output:

> Jan
>
> Feb
>
> Mar